# Linux проблема с запуском скриптов sh

Tags: linux, sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# figure out the absolute path to the script being run a bit
# non-obvious, the ${0%/*} pulls the path out of $0, cd's into the
# specified directory, then uses $PWD to figure out where that
# directory lives - and all this in a subshell, so we don't affect
# $PWD

GAMEROOT=$(cd "${0%/*}" && echo $PWD)

#determine platform
UNAME=`uname`
if [ "$UNAME" == "Darwin" ]; then
   # prepend our lib path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=${GAMEROOT}:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
elif [ "$UNAME" == "Linux" ]; then
   # prepend our lib path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${GAMEROOT}:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
fi

if [ -z $GAMEEXE ]; then
    if [ "$UNAME" == "Darwin" ]; then
      GAMEEXE=hl_osx
    elif [ "$UNAME" == "Linux" ]; then
      GAMEEXE=hl_linux
    fi
fi

ulimit -n 2048

# and launch the game
cd "$GAMEROOT"

STATUS=42
while [ $STATUS -eq 42 ]; do
    ${DEBUGGER} "${GAMEROOT}"/${GAMEEXE} -game dod $@
    STATUS=$?
done
exit $STATUS
```

Текст ошибки при запуске:

```
/root/dod.sh: 13: [: Linux: unexpected operator
/root/dod.sh: 16: [: Linux: unexpected operator
/root/dod.sh: 22: [: Linux: unexpected operator
/root/dod.sh: 24: [: Linux: unexpected operator
/root/dod.sh: 36: /root/dod.sh: /root/: Permission denied
```

Скрипт просто не запускается. Хочу узнать как исправить данную ошибку. Скачал игрушку, скинул в папку и запускаю скрипт. Он ругается. В гугле найти решение ошибки не смог. В этом деле я профан, по этому прошу помощи.
При запуске #./dod.sh ничего не происходит
При запуске #bash ./dod.sh тоже.

```
root@GeenTeen:~$ cat -n dod.sh | grep 16 | hd
00000000  20 20 20 20 31 36 09 65  6c 69 66 20 5b 20 22 24  |    16.elif [ "$|
00000010  55 4e 41 4d 45 22 20 3d  3d 20 22 4c 69 6e 75 78  |UNAME" == "Linux|
00000020  22 20 5d 3b 20 74 68 65  6e 0a                    |" ]; then.|
0000002a
```

Comment: Это для установки игрушки

Comment: Вы скрипт разве от root'а запускаете? Положите в домашний каталог того пользователя, от имени которого запускаете.

Comment: У меня не создано пользователей. При установке только рут был. Я с него и пускаю.

Comment: Код должен быть **в вопросе в виде текста**, но не картинкой и не в комментариях. Ладно, вопрос отредактировал. Теперь объясните, в чём проблема у вас, какой результат вы ожидаете получить и какой получаете фактически. Не стесняйтесь использовать кнопку [edit]. )

Comment: Удивительно! (это я после вывода `cat -n dod.sh ...`). Дело в том, что у меня в `Linux avp-ubu1 4.4.0-43-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 12 13:48:03 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` этот скрипт **работает**, естественно, завершаясь сообщением `./tt.sh: line 36: /home/avp/hashcode/hl_linux: No such file or directory`. Попробуйте в следующую после `#!/bin/bash` строку вставить код `[ A == A ] && echo It works! && exit` и напишите, что получилось

Comment: И еще одна догадка. Проверьте, что /bin/bash у Вас это в самом деле bash (а  не dash, ksh, sh или что-нибудь еще)

Comment: К коментарию @avp: сделайте $ ls -l /bin/bash       ........ это действительно может быть символьной ссылкой на dash

Answer (score 2):

Вангую, конечно... Но, вероятно, вы запускаете скрипт `#sh ./dod.sh`

Нужно запускать просто `#./dod.sh` либо `#bash ./dod.sh`

Сейчас, пожалуй, глупый вопрос будет... А Вы не забыли сделать chmod?

```
chmod +x dod.sh 
chmod +x hl.sh 
chmod +x hl_linux
```

Comment: Не помогает.  Ничего не происходит.

Comment: Обновил ответ _15 символов_

Answer (score 2):

Для начала: не надо работать от рута. Создайте пользователя. Это будет правильно. 
Потом посмотрите в каких строках ошибку выдает. Если приглядеться - то это все строки с if.
Соответственно башу не нравится сравнение:

```
if [ "$UNAME" == "Darwin" ]
```

и аналогичные. Насколько известно мне - сравнения происходят в баше:

```
if [ $env = "string" ]
```

Читать тут: https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/bash_scripting_guide/c2171.html

Если не поможет - попробуйте по совету Александра Блинова - попробуйте указать когда запускаете:

```
$ bash script_name.sh
```

Comment: Только через bash (конкретно данный скрипт из-за `cd` вот тут: `GAMEROOT=$(cd "${0%/*}" && echo $PWD)`)надо запускать с указанием оглавления, например `bash ./script-name.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Код скрипта
 **в вопросе** абсолютно работоспособен (в интерпретаторе **bash**).

Внимательно проверьте (например, командой `cat -n dod.sh | grep 16 | hd` (или  чем-нибудь аналогичным на Ваш выбор)) символы вокруг `[` в строках на которые у Вас идет ругань, в самом ли деле это пробелы.

Возможно также (судя по характерной диагностике -- `[: Linux: unexpected operator`), что у Вас `/bin/bash` либо является ссылкой на [dash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dash), либо просто заменен на эту команду, которая выдает именно такую диагностику для неизвестной ей 
операции `==`.